Property of the conditional expectation
Let $X$ and $Y$ two random variables. Which are the properties that a function $f$ should have to guarantee that
$$
E(Y|X) = E(Y|f(X)) ?
$$

You need $X$ and $f(X)$ to generate the same $\sigma$-algebra. Conditions on $f$ such that this is true can be found, for example, here.

... which says $f$ should be an injective Borel-measurable function.
